# Composite event is not triggered in MassTransit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, masstransit, automatonymous

My problem that Composite Event isn't not triggered when I got all the required events (in my case `LinkContract`, `LinkCustomer`). And there is a strange thing - when I send `LinkContract` event, value of `ProcessingStatus` became `1` and then when I got the second event `LinkCustomer` it changes to `0`, but I thought it must be `3`.
Can someone explain why this happens and my composite event isn't trigger?

I've registered composite event in my MassTransitStateMachine:

```cs
using MassTransit;
using Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents;
using Serilog;

namespace Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines;

public class BillingStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<BillingState>
{
    public BillingStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);
        
        Event(() => LinkCustomer, e => e
            .CorrelateById(x => x.Message.CustomerId));
        Event(() => LinkContract, e => e
            .CorrelateById(x => x.Message.CustomerId));

        Initially(
            When(LinkCustomer)
                .Then(HandleLinkCustomer)
                .TransitionTo(Processing),
            When(LinkContract)
                .Then(HandleLinkContract)
                .TransitionTo(Processing));
        
        During(Processing,
            When(LinkContract)
                .Then(HandleLinkContract),
            When(LinkCustomer)
                .Then(HandleLinkCustomer));

        CompositeEvent(() => PaymentSucceeded, 
            x => x.ProcessingStatus,
            CompositeEventOptions.IncludeInitial,
            LinkContract, LinkCustomer);
        
        During(Processing,
            When(PaymentSucceeded)
                .Then(HandlePaymentSucceeded)
                .TransitionTo(Paid));
    }
    
    public State Processing { get; }
    public State Paid { get; }
    
    public Event PaymentSucceeded { get; }
    public Event<ContractCreated> LinkContract { get; }
    public Event<CustomerCreated> LinkCustomer { get; }

    private static void HandleLinkCustomer(BehaviorContext<BillingState, CustomerCreated> context)
    {
        context.Saga.CustomerId = context.Message.CustomerId;
        Log.Information("Customer was linked: {CustomerId}", context.Saga.CustomerId);
    }

    private static void HandleLinkContract(BehaviorContext<BillingState, ContractCreated> context)
    {
        context.Saga.ContractId = context.Message.ContractId;
        context.Saga.CustomerId = context.Message.CustomerId;
        Log.Information("Contract was linked: {ContractId}", context.Saga.ContractId);
    }

    private static void HandlePaymentSucceeded(BehaviorContext<BillingState> context)
    {
        Log.Information("Billing was paid: {ContractId} & {CustomerId}",
            context.Saga.ContractId, context.Saga.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

and the following state:

```cs
using MassTransit;

namespace Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines;

public class BillingState : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public CompositeEventStatus ProcessingStatus { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid ContractId { get; set; }
}
```

There is DI configuration:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(opts =>
{
    opts.SetEndpointNameFormatter(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

    opts.AddConsumers(assembly);
    opts.AddSagaStateMachine<BillingStateMachine, BillingState>()
        .RedisRepository(x => x
            .DatabaseConfiguration("<connection_string>"));

    opts.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
        cfg.AutoStart = true;
        cfg.Host("localhost", 5672, "/", r =>
        {
            r.Username("guest");
            r.Password("guest");
        });
    });
});
```

Also if this will help, there are logs:

```
[13:04:29 INF] Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost/
[13:05:16 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents:ContractCreated, type: fanout, durable
[13:05:16 DBG] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents:ContractCreated eb480000-25c5-9e68-3b62-08da536d8a2f Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.ContractCreated
[13:05:16 INF] HTTP POST /api/User/contract responded 204 in 322.4377 ms
[13:05:16 DBG] SAGA:Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines.BillingState:00000000-507f-1f77-bcf8-6cd799439011 Created Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.ContractCreated
[13:05:16 DBG] SAGA:Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines.BillingState:00000000-507f-1f77-bcf8-6cd799439011 Added Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.ContractCreated
[13:05:16 INF] Contract was linked: 00000000-507f-1f77-bcf8-6cd799439011
[13:05:16 DBG] RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/billing-state eb480000-25c5-9e68-3b62-08da536d8a2f Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.ContractCreated Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines.BillingState(00:00:00.4622311)
[13:06:29 DBG] Declare exchange: name: Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents:CustomerCreated, type: fanout, durable
[13:06:29 DBG] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents:CustomerCreated eb480000-25c5-9e68-751a-08da536db5cb Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.CustomerCreated
[13:06:29 INF] HTTP POST /api/User/customer responded 204 in 360.3700 ms
[13:06:29 DBG] SAGA:Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines.BillingState:00000000-507f-1f77-bcf8-6cd799439011 Used Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.CustomerCreated
[13:06:29 INF] Customer was linked: 00000000-507f-1f77-bcf8-6cd799439011
[13:06:29 DBG] RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/billing-state eb480000-25c5-9e68-751a-08da536db5cb Sandbox.WebApi.Models.StateEvents.CustomerCreated Sandbox.WebApi.StateMachines.BillingState(00:00:00.3579677)
```

Comment: Please specify which version of MassTransit you are using.

Comment: I'm using 8.0.3

Comment: Could you try the latest -develop packages? I found a major regression in the composite event processing that I reverted yesterday, that was introduced in v8.

Comment: It's working on 8.0.4-develop.485. When will it be released? So I will wait for 8.0.4. I've temporary implemented workaround with the same logic

Comment: No ETA at this point, there are a lot of underlying changes in 8.0.4 that need to settle out before I can call it ready.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, is it some strange serialization issue with Redis? Change the composite event status to an `int`:

`public int ProcessingStatus { get; set; }`

Also, make sure you have retry configured on the saga so that any concurrency issues are retried.

Comment: I've tried both `int` and `CompositeEventStatus`

Comment: When ProcessingStatus is int, after received first event `LinkContract` I got ProcessingStatus = 1, then after I received the second one `LinkCustomer` ProcessingStatus still 1